# OS Error: Not a directory when creating a directory in temporary directory

Tags: android, flutter, dart, path-provider

I'm trying to create a directory in my temp / cache directory to store a file after downloading it but I seem to keep getting the Creation failed, path = 'xxxxx' (OS Error: Not a directory, errno = 20) error

```
createDirectory(String name) async {
  final fileDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final Directory newFileDir = await Directory('${fileDir.path}/$name').create(recursive: true);
}
```

I tried `getApplicationCacheDirectory()` too but I got the same error but when I changed use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, it manage to create the directory without any error. Am I missing anything or is it not allowed to create a directory in the temp directory?

Comment: Is there a chance that a non-directory already exists with that path?

Comment: I just checked and yes. After deleting the non-directory then the directory is able to be created without an error. Thank you